# Seeking a replacement for DDX

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

The DDX technology was created for linking resources with class members (for example). In my solution I need to make the connection between myCCtreeCtrl (instant of CCtreeCtrl) does not living in resources with class member CCtreeCtrl. 
Now I have CTreeCtrl in resouces and silmple doDataExchange:

```
#define IDC_TREE_LAYER0                 2000   
#define IDC_TREE_LAYER1                 2001
#define IDC_TREE_LAYER2                 2002


// ============================================================================
void ForcesGUI::doDataExchange( int id0, int id1, int id2, CDataExchange* pDX )
// ============================================================================
{
   DDX_Control(pDX, id0, m_tree[0].data);
   DDX_Control(pDX, id1, m_tree[1].data);
   DDX_Control(pDX, id2, m_tree[2].data);
}
```

but in future it will be necessary to delete CCtreeCtrl from resources and make instance.

You'll ask me why do you need deleting from resources?

The answer is: In project I have 3 CCtreeCtrls each of them live on his own bar. There is no different betwen them. That is why I want to use 1 bar class with 1 tree on it instead of redundancy. After I'll create 3 instance of bar and here appears problem with DDX wich does not work here.

Have you any ideas how can I replace basic DDX? May be it will be WinAPI or something else. In any case thanks for help.

Comment: It is difficult to decipher your question. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: In two words I need to write method (like DDX) which will carry out the interaction between object myCCtreeeCtrl and class member m_CCtreeCtrl. The problem is that I can't use resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the control isn't generated automatically from a dialog resource, you'll have to create it with the [`Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yhc9kx4.aspx) method. You'll want to do this in `OnInitDialog` or whatever equivalent is in your parent window. By creating the window with `Create` it will automatically be connected to the object you created it from - no need for DDX_Control.

Comment: Perfectly. Thanks, Mark, I even did not imagine that is so easy.